# Norton 360 Remote Desktop Machine Name / IP restriction not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, firewall, norton-360

I am trying to access a windows 10 host machine that has Norton 360 installed (firewall and antivirus) on it via Remote Desktop (RDP). I have added a rule in Norton 360 to allow RDP access to only 1 machine (by machine name and IP address) in the local network as shown below in the screen shots.

However, there seems to be absolutely no restrictions to what client machine can access the host. I am able to access the host machine from any machine on the local network.

Norton Chat support suggested moving the rule all the way to the top of all the rules but that still did NOT work. Norton Chat support and thereafter phone support had no further ideas as to why this is not working.

It seems straight forward but it does NOT work. Is there a step missing?

--- follow up ---

Upon suggestion of a superuser member (harrymc) I added another rule to restrict RDP access to all computers / machines (screenshots attached). This rule was moved to to top of all the rules.

Same as before I can access the windows 10 host machine via RDP from any machine on the local network. Adding the additional restriction rule did NOT help restricting RDP to only 1 machine.

It almost seems like RDP is either on or off for all machines.

--- follow up ---

Per superuser member suggestion moved the block all rule one below the allow RDP to 1 machine rule.

Again same as before I can access the windows 10 host machine via RDP from any machine on the local network.

[image: Norton Rule 1 A]

[image: Norton Rule 1 B]

[image: Norton Rule 1 C]

[image: Norton Rule 2 A]

[image: Norton Rule 2 B]

[image: Norton Rule 2 B]

[Norton Rule positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkf9V.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to restrict external clients to your network or internal clients to your network. There also isn’t an attached PDF

Comment: I am trying to restrict all RDP clients external and internal except for only 1 internal client. (sorry about the PDF mention it was actually the images - edited the post - THX)

Comment: Why don't you just deny all traffic then only allow traffic from the single client?

Comment: I did following the recommendation of another member. See the last 3 images. Did not make a difference. I can still RDP from any other client on the network to the host. It's like nothing happened when the rule was added.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Norton. I would just blackhole, the two clients, at the network level instead of relying on software Firewall running on the clients. Explicitly block to/from traffic on each client, then implicitly explicitly allow to/from traffic on that specific port, between only the two clients

Comment: It is slowly looking like a Norton issue. Looks straight forward but not getting the expected results. Still hoping someone pops up and says you forgot this. Anything else you might think of before I go hunt a network guy down please let me know and thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you screenshots are the only thing you did, then I remark that you
have added as rule for allowing your computer through the firewall,
but you're missing a rule for blocking RDP by all other computers.

This explains why all computers can RDP to yours without a problem.

Comment: Added the rule as you suggested and moved it up to the top of all rules. Still the same phenomena as it will allow all clients (internal network) to access. Almost seems like it does not see the exception and the system is either all on or off in terms of allowing RDP clients. Thank you for you suggestion.

Comment: The Allow rule should be the top one.

Comment: Moved the allow rule to #1 position and the block all rule to the #2 position (see last image). Still the same phenomena as it will allow all clients (internal network) to access. Very strange behavior. Thank you for you suggestions.